# This Query Takes Long Time to load, how i can make Fast for result load?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query takes too much time to load; can anyone make it quicker?

```
SELECT 
    c.tank_name, c.tank_id,
    (SELECT TOP 1 b.Level FROM TrackMessages b 
     WHERE b.IMEI = a.IMEI AND b.Timestamp >= @StartDate 
     ORDER BY b.Timestamp ) AS OpeningBalance,
    (SELECT TOP 1 b.Level FROM TrackMessages b 
     WHERE b.IMEI = a.IMEI AND b.Timestamp >= @EndDate 
     ORDER BY b.Timestamp ) AS ClosingBalance,
    (SELECT TOP 1 b.Temp FROM TrackMessages b 
     WHERE b.IMEI = a.IMEI AND b.Timestamp >= @StartDate 
     ORDER BY b.Timestamp) AS StartTemperature,
    (SELECT TOP 1 b.Temp FROM TrackMessages b 
     WHERE b.IMEI = a.IMEI AND b.Timestamp >= @EndDate 
     ORDER BY b.Timestamp ) AS EndTemperature 
FROM 
    device as a
JOIN 
    tbl_static_tank_info as c ON c.tank_id = a.owner_id
WHERE 
    c.client_id = @AppId AND  c.tank_Id IN ({levels})
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server, not MySQL syntax.  Are you sure you tagged with the right database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff its SQL Server

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah its SQL server

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hope you can help to solve this and Guide me to write Quick Query

Comment: Can you describe us wt do you want to get data from table. Why you doing tbis ?

Comment: @NeerajPathak Column name will define it self why i m using tables please check

Answer (score 0):

This is your query, reformatted and using meaningful table aliases so it can be better understood:

```
SELECT sti.tank_name, sti.tank_id,
       (SELECT TOP 1 tm.Level 
        FROM Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages tm 
        WHERE tm.IMEI = d.IMEI AND tm.Timestamp >= @StartDate
        ORDER BY tm.Timestamp
       ) AS OpeningBalance,
       (SELECT TOP 1 tm.Level 
        FROM Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages tm
        WHERE tm.IMEI = d.IMEI AND tm.Timestamp >= @EndDate
        ORDER BY tm.Timestamp
       ) AS ClosingBalance,
       (SELECT top 1 tm.Temp 
        FROM Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages tm 
        WHERE tm.IMEI = d.IMEI AND tm.Timestamp >= @StartDate
        ORDER BY tm.Timestamp
       ) AS StartTemperature,
       (SELECT top 1 tm.Temp 
        FROM Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages tm 
        WHERE tm.IMEI = d.IMEI AND tm.Timestamp >= @EndDate
        ORDER BY tm.Timestamp
       ) AS EndTemperature 
FROM  GatexServerDB.dbo.device d JOIN
      GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info sti
      ON sti.tank_id = d.owner_id
WHERE sti.client_id = @AppId AND sti.tank_Id IN ({levels})
```

There are some tricks you can play by restructuring the query.  I would start with indexes on `tbl_static_tank_info(client_id, tank_id)`, `device(owner_id, IMEI)`, and `TrackMessages(IMEI, Timestamp, Temp, Level)`.

The first index matches the `where` clause conditions.  `client_id` is first because of the equality (and SQL Server doesn't support something called a skip-scan).

The second index is a covering index for `device`, with the first column the one used for the `join`.  The second column can be including using `include` rather than as a key.

The third index is for the correlated subqueries.  This is a covering index for all the subqueries.  The last two columns can be included using `include` rather than as keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following indexes to your tables:

```
create index ix1 on Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages (IMEI, Timestamp, Level);

create index ix2 on Microframe.dbo.TrackMessages (IMEI, Timestamp, Temp);

create index ix3 on GatexReportsDB.dbo.tbl_static_tank_info (tank_id, client_id);
```